# How to rotate the Z axis from code in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

How can i make z axis change from code in unity?
I tried this:

```
    if (Input.GetKey("e")) {
    Car.transform.rotate(xAngle, yAngle, zAngle);
}
```

and it tells me that Transform does not contain rotate.
What should i do?

Comment: Does you car have a rigidbody? If yes i suggest you to use a relative torque https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a [relative Torque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque.html) or use the Rotation of the [Transform Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html):

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3 eulerAngles, Space relativeTo)
```

so for example you would use:

```
Car.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x,y,z), Space.Self)
```